# Reserved method names in MS Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

In VBA for MS-Word, and undoubtedly the rest of Office, there are some 'special' method (macro) names that intercept certain keystrokes / UI commands; for example:

> Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> (or the undo icon on the QAT) is intercepted by `Public Sub EditUndo()`
>
> Pressing <kbd>Ctrlk</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> (or the redo icon on the QAT) is intercepted by `Public Sub EditRedo()`

The MS API documentation covers [EditUndo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.editundo) and [EditRedo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.editredo), and helps find some other methods that can be overridden.

But neither `NextCell` nor `PrevCell` seem to be included in the VBA API documentation. For example <kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior is altered whenever the selection is in a document table:

> Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> is intercepted by `Public Sub NextCell()`
>
> Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is intercepted by `Public
>   Sub  PrevCell()`

This left me wondering if there are any other special method names... and how to find them.

So, my question (answer found during the asking) is:

### Where can I find a comprehensive list of method names for MS-Word that can be used to override default commands?

Comment: For the person that voted to close, 'off topic, not about programming'. OMG - this question is about a specific programming problem _(avoiding method names that could have unintentional consequences)_ AND it also happens to be about a specific software tool commonly used by programmers _(VBA)_; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. It also provides information that is not that easy to find elsewhere. Perhaps read the guidelines, thanks for your time, come back soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The [open specification 2.9.75 Fci](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-doc/e86aecb4-bb67-4de2-9b06-37771115f274) provides a long list of method names some of which can over-ride commands.

> The Fci enumeration provides a 13-bit unsigned integer that specifies
>   a built-in command.

[image: snippet from 2.9.75 Fci]

For example, you might like to include a method like:

```
Sub UnlinkFields()
    ' Intercepts Ctrl+Shift+F9 to prevent user from 
    ' unlinking fields and breaking your document
End Sub
```

---

**Some Usage Notes**

- If you put these methods in the Normal.dotm template they should have
  global scope and apply to all open documents.
- Putting the method into a specific document template means it will
  only apply to documents based on that template
- The module can be Public or Private, i.e. they still work if you use
  `Option Private Module`.
- The method can be Public or Private (at least as far as my testing
  goes)

The method can be a Sub or Function, for example both of these work:

```
Private Function DoubleUnderline()
    ' Ctrl + Shift + D
    Stop
End Function
```

and

```
Public Sub DoubleUnderline()
    ' Ctrl + Shift + D
    Stop
End Function
```