# How to ask for confirmation before allowing a Word document to close?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I work with 2 different keyboard layouts (qwerty and azerty), and am constantly switching between the two using Alt-Shift.  Sometimes when I reach for Ctrl-Z to undo, I get instead Ctrl-W which closes the document.  Generally speaking I would in these situations get a Save Prompt, which would alert me to my mistake.  However, I am now using OneDrive, with Autosave on the documents I'm working on.  As a result, there is never this save prompt.  The document is instantly closed and, worse, the undo that I was trying to effect is no longer present when the document is re-opened.

I would like to use VBA attached to the Normal Template, such that, on closing any document created with the VBA template, I will check to see if Autosave is turned on, and if it is, confirm before closing with a messagebox.
Obviously if the user doesn't confirm (e.g. chooses Cancel) then the document should not be closed.

Initially I put my code on Document_Close, but soon realised that here it's too late to Cancel the close.  This is no good to me.
Then, based on some online code, I put my code in a class module (EventClassModule).    In the ThisDocument module, I initiate the class, and activate the event handler.
My code doesn't ever seem to run, or in anycase, breakpoints don't kick in.

I'm a little unsure of where Normal stops and my normal document begins...

In ThisDocument of Normal Template, I have this VBA

```vb
Dim X As New EventClassModule

Sub Register_Event_Handler()
    Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Register_Event_Handler
End Sub
```

And I have a class module called EventClassModule with the following

```vb
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim res As VbMsgBoxResult

    If Me.AutoSaveOn Then
        res = MsgBox("OK to Confirm", vbOKCancel, "Closing Document")
        If res = vbCancel Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I would like a prompt to confirm saving, any time a document is closed and the autosave option is turned off.

Comment: The VBA code looks as if it would do what you want. What happens instead?

Comment: Nothing happens...that I can see.  And if I put a breakpoint on If Me.Auto…. it never gets hit.

Comment: So this morning my code seems to be getting hit.  It was giving me an error, so I changed Me.AutoSaveOn to Doc.AutoSaveOn, and this seems to be working!  (But it wasn't yesterday, so I'll stay vigilant.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way, include a method like this:

```
Public Sub DocClose()
    ' Disables Ctrl + W  (but not other close methods, e.g. Alt + F4, menus, [X])
    ' Your code here:
    ActiveDocument.Close 
End Sub
```

Basically there are some method names that are used internally by MS-Word, and if you include them in your code they will prevent the default action.  If you leave the sub empty it will effectively disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

See here for more information: [Reserved method names in MS Word VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712471/reserved-method-names-in-ms-word-vba/56712472#56712472)

---

#### Advantage 1 of this technique

If you use `Public WithEvents App As Word.Application` and your project gets reset for any reason, and fails to restart... `App` will be `Nothing` and none of the events will fire.

#### Advantage 2 of this technique

On the occasions that you actually *want* to close a document...  with this technique you wont get bugged by a (soon to become) annoying confirmation message - just sayin ;-)

Comment: I had never heard of these internal Word methods.  This is great!  If my technique fails me, I'll certainly give this ago.  Much simpler if it works as advertised.

Comment: @davidmckinney yup - I only found out about these a few days ago myself and, yeah... it's basically a free lunch.  Works in Word 2016 (64bit). Also there are advantages to keeping it simple, see edit. Cheers,

Comment: You're quite right.  This is the perfect solution to my problem.  I've replaced the old one, which indeed would quickly become annoying.

Comment: No worries - glad it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Document_Open event handler will only fire if the Normal template is opened via File | Open. To get code to respond when starting Word you need to use an AutoExec routine. Simply rename your routine as below. You can find further info on Auto macros [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/286310/description-of-behaviors-of-autoexec-and-autoopen-macros-in-word)

```
Public Sub AutoExec()
  Register_Event_Handler
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip and the link.  My original solution seems to be working now...but I'll try this out if I encounter any difficulties.